Prove that $a^ab^bc^c$ $\ge$ $a^bb^cc^a$
Prove that $a^ab^bc^c$ $\ge$ $a^bb^cc^a$
Prove it for positive rational numbers and such that you reach a proof for the general cases where a < b < c and vice versa.
From what i know there are two possible ways to reach an answer.
One helpful tip is the rearangement-innequality but it is not neccesary for one of the solutions.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality
Notation of the rearangment-innequalty that i am acustomed with is that of brackets along with two rows(but not a matrix)
This was the last question on my test on innequalitys and i was one of the few students to solve it.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3808295/42969

Oh, could not find that when searching but what should i do know that i know the question exists?, put my answer on their post and take this question down?

Since we assume $0<a<b<c$ denote $p=\frac{b-a}{a},\ q=\frac{c-b}{a}$  Now for proving
$$a\log a+b\log b+c\log c\geq a\log b+b\log c+c\log a\ \ \ (1)$$  we rewrite $(1)$ as
$$a\log a+b(\log a+\log (1+p))+c(\log a +\log (1+p+q))\geq a(\log a+\log (1+p))+b(\log a+\log (1+p+q))+c\log a$$which is equivalent to
$$b\log (1+p)+c\log (1+p+q))\geq a\log (1+p)+b\log (1+p+q)$$ or
$$a(1+p)\log (1+p)+a(1+p+q)\log (1+p+q))\geq a\log (1+p)+a(1+p)\log (1+p+q)$$ which is trivially true.

For the suggested solution we will use logarithms.
If $$a^ab^bc^c \ge a^bb^cc^a$$
then if we take the natural logarithm of both sides and the innequality must still hold
$$\ln((a^a)(b^b)(c^c)) \ge \ln((a^b)(b^c)(c^a))$$
Rule of logarithms
$$\ln(a^a)+\ln(b^b)+\ln(c^c)\ge \ln(a^b)+\ln(b^c)+\ln(c^a)$$
We can now use the rule of logarithms $\ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$
$$a\ln(a)+b\ln(b)+c\ln(c) \ge b\ln(a)+c\ln(b)+a\ln(c)$$
This is where we can use the rearangment innequality. Note that this is not a matrix and just a notation of the rearangment-innequality
$$\begin{bmatrix}ln(a)&ln(b)&ln(c)\\a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\ge\begin{bmatrix}\ln(a)&\ln(b)&ln(c)\\b&c&a\end{bmatrix}$$
We then extend the argument for all arrangments of the innequality between a,b and c
Other suggested solution which i solved during the test
This time we need to get away with the apparent cases of equality when there is one of the elements as 0 or if they are all equal in wich case we find equality.
Then we move to case 1: $a<b<c$
We can express the power of a number as $b=a+x\Rightarrow a^b=a^{a+x}$
We now make this statment: $b=a+x, c=b+y, a=c-x-y$ : and use it in our equation
$$a^ab^bc^c \ge a^{a+x}b^{b+y}c^{c-x-y}=a^aa^xb^bb^xc^cc^{-x}c^{-y}$$
Division by the right side product and rewriting of a negative power gives
$$1 \ge \frac{a^xb^y}{c^xc^y}$$
We remember that since $a<c\Rightarrow a^x<c^x$ our denominator is larger than our nominator which is definative proof of the innequality.
We can also go the other way and prove for other arrangments of the innequality between a,b and c

Should $\ln(a^a)\ln(b^b)\ln(c^c) \ge \ln(a^b)\ln(b^c)\ln(c^a)$ perhaps be $\ln(a^a) + \ln(b^b) + \ln(c^c) \ge \ln(a^b) + \ln(b^c) + \ln(c^a)$ ?
